# Export PNG from SVG on a Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

This is sort of a complicated question:

My goal is to take HTML, and export it as a PNG. I read that the best way to do this was to wrap HTML within an SVG and foreignObject element, and draw it on an HTML5 Canvas. The problem is, when I do that, I'm finding it impossible to export due to a `tainted canvas cannot be exported` error message. Here is my code:

```
var data = "<svg width=200 height=200>" +
            "<foreignObject width=100% height=100%>" +
            document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML +
            "</foreignObject>" +
            "</svg>";

var serialized = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data.toDOM());

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([serialized], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    window.open(canvas.toDataURL("image/png")); //this is the line with the error
}

img.src = url;
```

I have verified most of this is working, with the exception of that `canvas.toDataURL()` call. Am I missing something here? Is there a way to get this to work I'm overlooking? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SVG taints a canvas in modern browsers.

You can no longer use the `foreignObject` hack to scrape an html element.

Modern browsers have plugged that hole for very good security reasons.

There are no cross-browser alternatives -- again for very good security reasons.

Chrome has a plugin called ScreenShot which lets you scrape content.

Comment: Wow, that is incredibly disappointing. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Could you provide any official references for this? This is only true for Chrome (webkit) at the moment, you can export SVG via canvas on FF (with some restrictions) and I believe there has been mentioning on the WHATWG to lift current restrictions with Chrome, not tight them with others, but please, any references that shows that this is being plugged (or is intended to).

Comment: If you run [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/zh2occ7q/) in FF you can see there is no tainting.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg, your fiddle runs in FF36.  It's "In-Development" for  Internet Explorer (or whatever they want to call it next): https://status.modern.ie/svgforeignobjectelement. The fiddle does not run in current Chrome, although it does run in older Chromes (fex, v27) As to Chrome, I keep seeing posts about "bugs related to foreignObject" so I'm not sure if your fiddle doesn't currently work in Chrome because they aren't supporting foreignObject or because they can't get it to work.

Comment: @markE no, it doesn't work in Chrome (it works in FF38 as well though). I got the impression Chromium would lift on this restriction (rather than Mozilla made it more strict), But we'll have to see I guess (off-topic: and I am still waiting for full support of TextMetrics - imagine if we could make competitors to online doc editors.. can't have that.. ;) ).